# Angularjs. I need to take out the a.txt and b.txt and c.txt in the string "a.txt,b.txt,c.txt," ignore commas using angularjs

Tags: c#, angularjs, model-view-controller

json result the string "a.txt,b.txt,c.txt," in model.File
string[] arr = "{{model.File}}".Trim(',').Split(new char[] { ',' });

I use in cshtml is that but in angularjs I do not know how to use it

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for an array of filenames? If so, you can use Javascript's  string.split() function:

```
var filenames = str.split(',');
```